# Model in Windows Phone using Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am using in my app the sqlite db. In order to create the db and fill it with data I had to create a winForms project where I am also using sqlite. The same model in these two different cases is not working properly. What I have in winForms and works is that:

```
[Parents]
int ParentId
string LName
virtual List<Child> Children

[Child]
int ChildId
int ParentId
int Count
```

Exactly the same code doesn't work in Windows Phone. The list of children is always empty. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the wrapper you're using. But - yes - generally most wrappers for sqlite do not support foreign key constructs. That means that you will have to write additional queries that will fetch these children from your local DB, like:

```
parent.Children = conn.Table<Children>().Where(c => c.ParentID == parentId).ToList();
```

That shouldn't be a problem with one or two levels of complexity. However if your data structure is a bit more sophisticated you could also go with an extension that will allow you to annotate relationships:

https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

Note that this is an extension for sqlite-net. I'd recommend this library as it's (imho!) the most popular one.